# Are there any free Ubuntu Servers that I can run my code on remotely?

Tags: linux

I've been training a neural net for the past couple of days on my handy Linux machine, however, it is taking forever (mostly because I'm using an older machine).  I'm sure if there even is a thing, but does anyone know of any free remote servers that are openly accessible for the public to run code on?  I'm not sure if this is even a thing, but I figured this would be the place to ask.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer

Comment: This is not really a thing (except for the free trials that andibing mentioned). Computers cost money, no matter what.

Comment: And the free tiers of such services may be slower still than your own computer.

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud providers offer some sort of free tier, so there is usually an opportunity to run a Linux for no (or very little) outlay.

For example, AWS, Azure and Google

- https://aws.amazon.com/free/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/
- https://cloud.google.com/free

Of course the high specification or more powerful a server is, you will likely nudge beyond the free tiers. But the cost/benefit of this may be worthwhile if you want your model to finish sooner.

The top tip for Cloud infrastructure is to make sure you turn off or delete what you are not using.
Hope that help you get started.

Comment: Thank you @andibing for the extremely helpful and exciting tip!  I'm looking at the google cloud server and it seems pretty cool!

Comment: Happy to help :-)